# Show exponential stability quadratic form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, stability-in-odes

Please help me with the following proof:

> Suppose $\dot x=f(x(t))$ and suppose that we have:
>
> $$ \frac{d}{dt}\left( x(t)^TPx(t) \right)\le -x(t)^TQx(t) $$
>
> where $P$ and $Q$ are symmetric positive definite matrices and the
>   time derivatives are taken along solutions of the system. Prove that
>   under this condition the system is exponentially stable in the sense
>   that solutions satisfy:
>
> $$ \|x(t)\|\le xe^{-\mu t}\|x(0)\| $$
>
> for some $c,\mu>0$.

**My attempt**:

The result is trivial for $P=Q=I$ (identity matrix). However, we have to show this for the general case. Since $P$ and $Q$ are symmetric, they are diagonalizable. So there exist transformation matrices $T_P$ and $T_Q$ such that:

$$
P=T_P\Lambda_P T_P^{-1}
$$

$$
Q=T_Q\Lambda_Q T_Q^{-1}
$$

where $\Lambda_P$ is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of $P$ along the diagonal and $\Lambda_Q$ is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of $Q$ along the diagonal. Since $P$ and $Q$ are positive definite, we know that these eigenvalues are all $>0$. Therefore we can write:

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left( x(t)^TT_P\Lambda_P T_P^{-1}x(t) \right)\le -x(t)^TT_Q\Lambda_Q T_Q^{-1}x(t) $$

$$
\Rightarrow \dot x(t)^TT_P\Lambda_P T_P^{-1}x(t)+x(t)^TT_P\Lambda_P T_P^{-1}\dot x(t)\le -x(t)^TT_Q\Lambda_Q T_Q^{-1}x(t)
$$

Since we are dealing with expression $\in\mathbb R$ in the above inequality, we have:

$$
\Rightarrow 2\dot x(t)^TT_P\Lambda_P T_P^{-1}x(t)\le -x(t)^TT_Q\Lambda_Q T_Q^{-1}x(t)
$$

$$
\Rightarrow 2f(x(t))^TT_P\Lambda_P T_P^{-1}x(t)\le -x(t)^TT_Q\Lambda_Q T_Q^{-1}x(t)
$$

*However, at this point I get stuck*. Since $T_Q\ne T_P$ generally, I cannot simply define a new coordinate $z=Tx$ such that only the diagonal matrices are left, where the answer will then follow directly by considering $n$ decoupled inequalities (assuming $x\in\mathbb R^n$). Could you please help me out how to continue? Or how to do the proof another way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use $T=P^{1/2}$ in $z=Tx$ to get
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(z^Tz)\le -z^T(P^{-1/2}QP^{-1/2})z\le-\lambda_{min}(P^{-1/2}QP^{-1/2})·z^Tz
$$

---

Because $P$ is SPD there exists a unique SPD square root $P^{1/2}$. Then also $P^{-1/2}QP^{-1/2}$ is SPD and has a minimal positive eigenvalue $\mu=\lambda_{min}$. From the inequality above one gets trivially
$$
z(t)^Tz(t)\le e^{-\mu t}z(0)^Tz(0)
$$
The conclusion is reached by observing that 
$$
x^Tx=z^TP^{-1}z\le \frac1{λ_{min}(P)}z^Tz
$$
which gives the multiplicative constant as, for instance,
$$
c=\frac{λ_{max}(P)}{λ_{min}(P)}x(0)^Tx(0)
$$

Comment: Thanks! But I don't understand the final inequality, specifically $-\lambda_{min}(P^{-1/2}QP^{-1/2})$. Is $P^{-1/2}QP^{-1/2}$ diagonal now (I don't think so)? Why can you say this? Also, intuitively I understand but I cannot rigorously show this - why can we say that if $\|z\|\to 0$ then $\|x\|\to 0$?

Comment: Also, why can we say that $P^{1/2}$ exists?